# Will it work long term? (Induction cooker 16 amp to 10 amp adaptor)

Tags: plug

Is it safe if I use two adaptors (13 amp and 10 amp) for my 16 amp induction cooker?  I can only plug it on a 220 v outlet.  The first adaptor has a switch though.  The induction cooker worked when I tried but I'm not sure if it can last a long time or if the cooker remains on for long periods.

[image: sketch]

Comment: Please provide a schematic, using the icon with the diode and the pencil. Your question so far in incomprehensible. How, exactly do you expect to connect these two adapters, and what do they do? Diagrams, please, not just words. But almost certainly the answer is no.

Comment: Not really a design question - could maybe be migrated to DIY?

Answer (score 1):

No. It likely won't even work SHORT-term.

We have no clue what you mean by "adapter". Even if your question were properly detailed, the answer would probably remain a solid NO.

Comment: Here's my drawing: http://imgur.com/un2pKCo

Comment: @malaki106 That's actually quite impressive. Sadly, it still doesn't make your question work here.

Comment: Your drawing makes it appear to be a 110V power outlet receptacle. But you have a 220V load (induction cooker). What country are you in? What is the rating of the power circuit(s)? There is so much important information missing, this scheme seems extremely dangerous.

Comment: I have boiled water again with this arrangement.  Only a few minutes but nothing happened.  It's the Philippines.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could work is if your induction cooker can be configured to draw only 13A. This would make it possible to use *without* an adaptor. Anything else is quite likely to cause a fire.

Comment: I used an extension once but it later got burned after few dozen uses.